# Cannot transfer Pixel to image in correct in right shape from cv code to cv2 code

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Recently I trying to do some image processing for my work.
Unfortunately that I keep trying to apply my old C++ code with cv support to python code with cv2 support.
It cannot work very well... Can anyone help me?

Original C++ Code:

```
#define IMAGE_WIDE  40
#define IMAGE_LENGTH    30
#define CHANNELS    3

DNN_image_out = cvCreateImage(cvSize(IMAGE_WIDE, IMAGE_LENGTH), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
for(int k = 0; k < IMAGE_LENGTH; k++){  //縦
        for(int l = 0; l < IMAGE_WIDE; l++){    //横
            DNN_image_out[i]->imageData[(k * IMAGE_WIDE + l)*3 +0] = DNN_image_tmp[(k * IMAGE_WIDE + l)*3 + 0 ];
            DNN_image_out[i]->imageData[(k * IMAGE_WIDE + l)*3 +1] = DNN_image_tmp[(k * IMAGE_WIDE + l)*3 + 1 ];
            DNN_image_out[i]->imageData[(k * IMAGE_WIDE + l)*3 +2] = DNN_image_tmp[(k * IMAGE_WIDE + l)*3 + 2 ];
        }
    }
```

---

My Python CV2 code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def split_channel3(array,width,height):
    R=[]
    G=[]
    B=[]
    for k in range(height):
        for l in range(width):
            R.append(array[(k * width + l)*3 +0])
            G.append(array[(k * width + l)*3 +1])
            B.append(array[(k * width + l)*3 +2])
    R = np.asarray(R)
    G = np.asarray(G)
    B = np.asarray(B)
    return [R,G,B]


[R,G,B] = split_channel3(img,40,30)
R = R.reshape(40,30,1)
G = G.reshape(40,30,1)
B = B.reshape(40,30,1)
Color_img = np.dstack((R,G))
Color_img = np.dstack((Color_img,B))
cv2.imshow('image',Color_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Is my logic wrong? Or what should I change in python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `cv2.split`, without the need of your custom function nor `reshape`:

```
B,G,R = cv2.split(img)
```

and then evantually use:

```
Color_img  = cv2.merge((B,G,R))
```

Remember that the channels are B,G,R by default in OpenCV, and not R,G,B.